# How to filter array using computed property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do I filter through an array using a computed property in `Vue.js 2.0`? This task was quite trivial in older versions of `Vue`, but now it is more involved. I am displaying data in a table:

```
 <tr v-for="person in filterPeople">
  <td>{{person.name}}</td>
  <td>{{person.age}}</td> 
</tr>
```

and I have an input field where I can filter through the names and ages. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here:

```
computed: {

  filterPeople: function(){
    var self = this
    return this.people.filter(function(p){
      return p.name.indexOf(self.searchDetails) > - 1
   })  
  }
}
```

If I type in the input it does not filter the people by name or age as I expect. Demo: http://codepen.io/p-adams/pen/AXPKko

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code directly in the question body.

Comment: Edited my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is really simple. You are using an input tag inside of a table. Try adding a containing div tag. Give it the app id and put the input element in it. This should fix the problem.

```
<div id="app">
  <input
         class="form-control"
         v-model="searchDetails"
         placeholder="filter by name or age"
         >
    <table class="table table-striped" >
      <thead>
      ...rest of code
```

Vue is still constrained by some of the rules of HTML and one of those is table tags can only have certain tags as direct children.

Comment: Ahh yes. Not sure how I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: It's actually somewhat easy to do when you are thinking in terms of Vue. Because normally you have a whole lot more flexibility with templates.

Comment: Okay.  I wonder why I am unable to filter by age. Seems to only work with the names. Things were much easier with built-in filters.

Comment: `p.name.indexOf(self.searchDetails) > - 1` is only filtering by `p.name`. You may need to write two filter functions and use one if the `searchDetails` is text and another if it is a number.

Comment: Perhaps because the number coming in through `input` is actually a string and my filter is trying to match it to an integer value. Either case, it does seem like I need two filter function.

Comment: Like I said in the previous comment you are sorting base on `p.name` you need to have a sort function based on `p.age`. As is it is the sort function never even looks at the value of `p.age`